# how to access to the web page with wrong database configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot, datasource, hikaricp

i used spring boot + HikariPool to build a web application.i want to export the WAR files and deliver to customers without data source configuration.because i do not know the correct data source info for every customer.so i create a page in my application that customer themselves can access to this page and add data source, then save it, in my java code, i will store the info into a Property file and restart spring boot application context to reload the correct data source from the Property file into the application. and the application will work well with the right data source configuration. But what the problem is, my service can not be up without data source configured or with wrong data source configuration. so customer can not access to the page to configure the correct data source. please give me some advice, thanks in advance

Comment: You might want to create a Mock-DataSource, which will lead all calls to nirvana or just general behave like a *no-op*

Comment: thank you. i will try it now